# Issue in connecting with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When trying to connect with the mongoDB through Mongoose. Getting an error as :

Error: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBGag.png)

Comment: You are not retrieving the `MONGO_URI` environment variable correctly. Did you use the `dotenv` library in your `server.js` file?

Answer (score 1):

you must be sure that the **process.env.MONGO_URI** is loaded correctly,

at the moment you are almost certainly passing `undefined`,

in case you work with an **.env** file try to install

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

and put

```
require('dotenv').config();
```